# Liquibase: <changeSet> with multiple SQL statements in <sql> using parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, liquibase

I need to run a prepared statement in Liquibase:

```
<changeSet id="53" author="foo">
    <sql dbms="!h2, mysql" splitStatements="true">
        SET @table_name = 'AUDIT_EVENT';
        SET @column_name = 'ACTOR_ID';
        SET @constraint_name = (
        SELECT rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS rc
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS kcu
        ON kcu.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = rc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
        AND kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        WHERE kcu.TABLE_NAME = @table_name
        AND kcu.COLUMN_NAME = @column_name
        );
        SET @s = concat('ALTER TABLE ', @table_name, ' DROP FOREIGN KEY ', @constraint_name);
        PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

If I set `splitStatements` to true, then I think parameters don't persist across statements so understandably I get an error saying that `@s` is NULL:

```
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
to use near 'NULL' at line 1 [Failed SQL: PREPARE stmt FROM @s]
```

If I set `splitStatements` to false, and also delete all but the first two `SET`s to make sure it's not the nested `SELECT` causing the issue, I get this:

```
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
to use near 'SET @column_name = 'ACTOR_ID'' at line 2 [Failed SQL: SET @table_name = 'AUDIT_EVENT';
        SET @column_name = 'ACTOR_ID';]
```

I assumed then the issue with with the `endDelimiter` defaulting to `;`. So I tried `FOO`:

```
    <sql dbms="!h2, mysql" splitStatements="false" endDelimiter="FOO">
        SET @table_name = 'AUDIT_EVENT';
        SET @column_name = 'ACTOR_ID';
        FOO
    </sql>
```

To which I get...

```
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
to use near 'SET @column_name = 'ACTOR_ID';
            FOO' at line 2 [Failed SQL: SET @table_name = 'AUDIT_EVENT';
            SET @column_name = 'ACTOR_ID';
            FOO]
```

I feel like I don't understand what's going on. I checked SQL does work in MySQL Workbench. Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

So, I thought *splitStatements=false* got me past the NULL `@s` error, and therefore hypothesized that parameters (or "user/session variables" as I now know to call them) must not persist when split. But that was all wrong. Those variables do persist across statements: for the duration of the session.

*splitStatements=false* simply masked the original error with a new one, which did indeed have to do with MySQL not allowing multiple queries at once. When I unblocked *that* using *allowMultiQueries=true*, I got a *new* error pointing to Line 1, which eventually got me to fix the *original* error, which was that my table name was wrong (uppercase instead of lowercase).

What I never realized was that, the table name being wrong also contributed to `@s` ending up NULL.

---

#### Old "Solution"

I didn't realize that MySQL doesn't allow multiple queries by default. I had to add that in the JDBC URL as a query parameter:

```
jdbc:mysql://%s:%d/%s?user=root&allowMultiQueries=true
```

As I understand, this is not a portable path. But since I'm using Liquibase to specify exactly what database to run these statements on, I think it's okay.